# How to kill all jobs in bash?

Tags: bash, job-control

So, I have some jobs like this:

```
sleep 30 | sleep 30 &
```

The natural way to think would be:

```
kill `jobs -p`
```

But that kills only the first `sleep` but not the second.

Doing this kills both processes:

```
kill %1
```

But that only kills at most one job if there are a lot of such jobs running.

It shouldn't kill processes with the same name but not run in this shell.

Comment: `killall sleep`

Comment: What do you do after running `sleep 30 | sleep 30`? Do you press `Control-z` and do `bg`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
pids=( $(jobs -p) )
[ -n "$pids" ] && kill -- "${pids[@]/#/-}"
```

`jobs -p` prints the PID of process group leaders. By providing a negative PID to `kill`, we kill all the processes belonging to that process group (`man 2 kill`). `"${pids[@]/#/-}"` just negates each PID stored in array `pids`.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in Ubu 20.04. (*kill* complained about negitave PID numnbers.). However, this works: `while [ -n "$(jobs -p)" ]; do kill %%; done`

Comment: @jpaugh I don't have U20.4. What you describe would be a bug to report to Bash, since negative PIDs are a property of the `kill(2)` system call and are part of the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html). Are you sure you copied-pasted my code correctly? What is your version of Bash? You can adapt my code to `/bin/kill` if Bash's kill is buggy (but IMO this is very unlikely).

Comment: I tried both `kill` and `/usr/bin/kill`; While I may have gotten the code wrong, I did verify the format of the PIDs before passing them to kill. I'm not going to look into this further, but hopefully this convo will help someone else.

Comment: For the reference, can you please add here the error messages produced by both Bash's builtin `kill` and `/bin/kill` when given a (valid) negative PID number? (/usr/bin/kill is surprising, you probably mean /bin/kill)

Comment: No, I used /usr/bin/kill. It's probably a symlink to /bin/kill (Ubuntu). I'll try to remember to re-run it when I'm in front of a linux box.

Answer (score 12):

A somewhat shorter version of xhienne's answer, but not pure-bash:

```
jobs -p | xargs -I{} kill -- -{}
```

Comment: "not pure-bash"; which part is not bash?

Comment: `xargs` is not part of bash. It's part of [`findutils`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/).

Comment: If brevity is desired, then I believe this is equivalent to `jobs -p | xargs -i kill -- -{}`

Comment: True, although `-i` is documented as deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Use `kill $( jobs -p )`... I love it.
Use this if you’ve jost got too many jobs for `kill`’s argv (it can happen I guess):

`killalljobs() { for pid in $( jobs -p ); do kill -9 $pid ; done ; }`

Comment: or simply use `pkill -s0` as shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483386/killall-for-this-terminal-only/483399)

Comment: @mosvy But what about less feature-rich environments, where no pkill/pgrep pair exists?

Comment: there you'll have to do it by hand ;-)

Comment: @mosvy and in a real hurry:/

Comment: Notice that `kill $(jobs -p)` will only kill process leaders ie. it won't kill the `sleep` in  `(sleep 3600 &)` or `(sleep 3600; true) &`. That may or may not be what you want. Also busybox has pgrep but no pkill, so `kill $(pgrep -s0)`.

Comment: ... and negating the pids as in the accepted answer will do the 2nd `sleep` in, but not the 1st.

Comment: @mosvy This also murders the active session, how do you avoid that?

Comment: will it? shells with job control are usually catching SIGTERM.

Comment: @mosvy what shell are you using?

Comment: any interactive shell -- the standard requires that any interactive shell ignore the SIGQUIT and SIGTERM signals.

Comment: @mosvy Yes of course, you’re right. I had written `kill -9 $(pgrep -s0)` in my panicohnooverload() shell function:/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pkill` and `pgrep` to kill a list of process names.

From the man page:

> **pgrep** looks through the currently running processes and lists the process IDs which matches the selection criteria to stdout. All the criteria have to match. For example,
>   pgrep -u root sshd
>   will only list the processes called sshd AND owned by root. On the other hand,
>   pgrep -u
>   root,daemon
>   will list the processes owned by root OR daemon.
>   **pkill** will send the specified signal (by default SIGTERM) to each process instead of listing them on stdout.

An example using `pgrep`, `pkill`,

```
$ pgrep -l script.sh
12406 script.sh
12425 script.sh

$ pkill $(pgrep script.sh)

$ cat signal-log
Name: ./script.sh Pid: 12406 Signal Received: SIGTERM
Name: ./script.sh Pid: 12425 Signal Received: SIGTERM
```

Answer (score 2):

This will kill all jobs, most recently created first:

```
while kill %%; do :; done
```

This stops when there are no more jobs to kill, and prints:

```
bash: kill: %%: no such job
```

Works in `zsh` too.

Comment: Or more exactly, it works only in `zsh`, not `sh` or `bash`.

Comment: Combined with the accepted answer, this becomes `while [ -n "$(jobs -p)" ]; do kill %%; done`. Prob slower, but no extraneous error message.

Comment: Works fine for me with `bash 4.4.20`.