# How to create a bunch of background processes in terminator terminals later kill them in bash

Tags: bash, gnome-terminator, sigint

I'm trying to write a batch script that creates new terminator terminals and then runs a process in each one. I want them to keep running in the background until I decide to kill them.

I want the first one to run for 10 seconds and then afterwards create a bunch of other terminator processes simultaneously.

This first part far works but now I want to, at the end, be able to press enter and send a SIGINT to every process that I started. I can't figure out a command that works for this purpose.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Running Teleop... (MAY TAKE SEVERAL SECONDS TO INITIALIZE)"

terminator -T "gazebo" -e "roslaunch cob_bringup_sim robot.launch 
robot:=cob4-8 robot_env:=ipa-apartment; bash" &

#wait 10 secons before starting nav and rviz otherwise will get error
((sleep 10) &&
(terminator -T "navigation" -e "roslaunch cob_navigation_global 
2dnav_ros_dwa.launch robot:=cob4-5 robot_env:=ipa-apartment; bash" &
terminator -T "rviz" -e "roslaunch cob_navigation_global rviz.launch; 
bash" &
terminator -T "arm_controller" -e "roslaunch cob_moveit_bringup 
demo.launch rviz_tutorial:=true robot:=cob4-8; bash" &
terminator -T "control_nodes" -e "cd catkin_ws; rosrun first_pkg 
control_nodes; bash" &
terminator -T "controller" -e "cd catkin_ws; rosrun first_pkg 
controller; bash" &
terminator -T "joystick" -e "rosrun joy joy_node; bash" &
#spawn objects
terminator -T "spawn_objects_launch" -e "roslaunch 
cob_default_env_config upload_object_locations.launch robot_env:=ipa- 
apartment; rosrun cob_bringup_sim spawn_object.py tomato_sauce; 
bash")) &

(
echo Press any key to to shutdown all processes
read varname
echo Shutting down...
#terminating all child processes
)
```

These are ROS commands but I assume there is no difference between them and generic commands in this case. I realize the code is quite messy and if there are any other issues you see with it I'd be glad to hear it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When run non-interactively (e.g. in a script), bash disables job control, so easy methods of killing background processes, such as those in [Kill all background jobs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43527/117549) or [How to kill all jobs in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/383497/117549) won't work by default.

The first thing I would do is to ensure that you're running bash by changing the sh-bang line to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Next, let's enable job control (aka ["monitor mode"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin)) so that we can use one of the easy solutions from those previous questions:

```
set -m
```

Next, I would simplify most of your subshell activity; you don't need them. With simplified commands, just to demonstrate the point:

```
#wait 10 seconds before starting nav and rviz otherwise will get error
sleep 10 || exit
terminator -T "navigation ... bash" &
terminator -T "rviz ... bash" &
...
terminator -T "spawn_objects_launch" &

echo Press any key to to shutdown all processes
read varname
echo Shutting down...
```

You don't have to start an entire subshell (and background it) for all of the terminator processes. You don't need to run the `sleep 10` in a subshell. You don't *really* need to test the return code of `sleep 10` in order to chain the subsequent commands, with `&&`. I've adapted the code to match the existing behavior: if the sleep command fails (say, you hit Control-C), then the script will exit and not start the subsequent terminator processes.

Lastly, add the code to kill off the child processes:

```
...
terminator -T "spawn_objects_launch" &

echo Press ENTER to shutdown all processes
read 
echo Shutting down...
kill $(jobs -p)
```

I rephrased the prompt; you'd need to enter (almost) any key and then press ENTER in order for the `read` command to see your input, so I simply suggest that the user press ENTER. Next, the `read` command accepts a variable name, but there's a default variable named `REPLY` that it will use if you don't specify your own variable name, so depending on whether that's more obvious to you, that's another option to simplify the code.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! Thanks for helping me clean it up too