# killall for this terminal only

Tags: kill

When debugging I often use `killall` to kill a process. This is really a bad habit because there might be more processes running of the same name on the system.

Normally the process I want to kill is a descendant from the same parent (or grandparent) as `killall` is started from. Often I want to kill a program started in the same terminal or a terminal in another tab (in Konsole).

Is there a way to tell `killall` (or another killer) to limit the scope to processes started from this terminal or processes that are descendants from the same (grand)parent?

Comment: Would this be an acceptable alternative? `ps` selects processes at the terminal scope by default, which could then be piped to `xargs kill`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to kill all processes from this session (processes which have the current tty as their controlling terminal):

```
tty=`tty`; pkill -t "${tty#/dev/}"
```

Or even simpler:

```
pkill -s 0
```

According to pkill(1):

> ```
> -s, --session sid,...
>
>  Only match processes whose process session ID is  listed.   Ses-
>  sion ID 0 is translated into pgrep's or pkill's own session ID.
> ```

Both the `-t` and the `-s` options could be combined (ANDed) with a pattern and other options, eg. `pgrep -s0 -x foo` for the processes from this session named exactly `foo`. Unfortunately, neither `pgrep` nor `pkill` support complex, `tcpdump`-style predicates.