# How to kill all background jobs in dash?

Tags: kill, background-process, job-control, dash, jobs

Simply `kill $( jobs -p )` [not work in dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360201/how-do-i-kill-background-processes-jobs-when-my-shell-script-exits#comment76126638_360275).
For example in dash:

```
$ sleep 999 &
$ kill $(jobs -p)
dash: 2: kill: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or
kill -l [exitstatus]
$
```

Comment: Are you really using `dash` as an interactive shell, or did you happen upon this when trying to debug some script? Notice that that `kill $(jobs -p)` will not kill all the background _jobs_, but only the job/program group _leaders_: even in `bash`, if you run `(sleep 3600; echo DONE) &`, and then `kill $(jobs -p)`, the `sleep` process will not be killed.

Comment: Anyways, you can run `jobs -p > tmpfile; kill $(cat tmpfile)` -- and that's the very best Q you can get while not questioning any of the dubious assumptions ;-)

Comment: Note that the hyperlinked problem is specific to the _Debian_ Almquist shell.  It is not exhibited by the _FreeBSD_ Almquist shell.

Comment: @mosvy Yes, I'm using `dash` as an interactive shell(i.e. both the "interactive" and the "monitor" options are enabled(i.e. on)).

Comment: Then you'll have to make do with copy&paste, a temporary file or a named pipe. Just in case it wasn't clear from my 1st comment, the linked stackoverflow answer is __incorrect__, as `kill $(jobs -p)` will __not__ kill all the background processes or jobs.

Comment: If you want to kill all the processes from the current _session_, use [`pkill -s0`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/483399/308316); but if your interractive shell you call that from is not the session leader, that may also kill processes not started from it.

Comment: @mosvy how can I write to named pipe without change the `jobs -p` result? `jobs -p > pipe; kill $(cat pipe)` just hanging, even I try `jobs -p &` I just get empty when read the pipe(`cat pipe`).

Comment: Do it backwards, run the `kill` asynchronously. `(kill -TERM $(sed s/^/-/ fifo)&); jobs -p > fifo`

Answer (score -1):

Make a bug report to the maintainers of `dash`.

It seems that `dash` does return empty output in case that `jobs` is run in a subshell.

Do you really need to use `dash`? It is know for not being POSIX compliant for several reasons.