# Can't grep or word count the output of jobs command in dash

Tags: shell, dash, jobs

This is what I tested in Arch's dash shell and FreeBSD's default sh shell, the results are the same.

```
$ sleep 100 &
$ jobs
[1] + Running                    sleep 100
$ jobs | wc
      0       0       0
$ jobs | grep 1
```

I can't `wc` or `grep` on the output of `jobs` command. The `jobs` command is shell built-in.

What is the reason for this? is it that `jobs` somehow prints different information in interactive shell and to pipe? I don't know details about that, but I knew about similar behavior of `ls`. I.e., you will see compact output of `ls` in shell, but `grep` will treat each file name in a standalone line instead.

Edit: I found a similar question: [How to kill all background jobs in dash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558911/how-to-kill-all-background-jobs-in-dash), that question is also due to not being able to get the output of `jobs` command.

Comment: How about redirecting output of jobs to temp file and reading from it?

Comment: @SHW do you know why this works? Where does `jobs` actually write?

Comment: @Panki, Not really. I just wanted a quick way to sort. But my first guess will be STDERR to STDOUT

Comment: @SHW redirecting to files indeed works, also it was suggested by someone else in the comment of the question I linked here. As for the stderr to stdout, if I am doing right, by `jobs 2>&1 | wc`, then it's not working either. Actually, if the `jobs` output was to stderr, it should be shown together with `wc`/`grep` output, instead of disappear.